# JVM Threaddump OnOutOfMemoryError Unrecognized option

Tags: java, out-of-memory, kill, thread-dump, java-opts

I want to collect a thread dump when an OutOfMemory error occurs.

I add this option on my run.conf script :

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/bin/kill -3 %p"
```

But at startup I have :

```
Unrecognized option: -3
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I tried with :

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"/bin/kill -3 %p\""
```

The result in process launched args is ok :

```
.... -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/bin/kill -3 %p"  ....
```

But the error at startup is the same :

```
Unrecognized option: -3
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quoting problem.  The `/bin/kill -3 %p` is not sent down as a single string to the JVM by the shell.

I would suggest trying single quotes instead (untested):

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='/bin/kill -3 %p'"
```